# Read LevelDB format from Matlab

Tags: matlab, caffe, feature-extraction, leveldb, matcaffe

I am working on Caffe. I already extract features using `extract_features.bin`, it will create a result as this figure below. It said that the feature will stored in LevelDB format. But, since I almost work in MATLAB, so I want to read this output on my MATLAB. But, I still cannot find a way how to do that. Anybody could help me?

[image: Screenshot of my levelDB output]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use python to read the leveldb, save it to mat-file and process it in Matlab.

For this workaround to work, you'll need [`py-leveldb`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/py-leveldb/) (and python...)

In python

```
import leveldb      # for reading leveldb
import numpy as np  # for manipulating the data
import scipy.io     # for writing to mat file

data = []
db = leveldb.LevelDB('/path/to/output400_flickr_fc7')
for key, value in db.RangeIter():
    data.append( np.array(value) )

scipy.io.savemat('/path/to/output400_flickr_fc7.mat', {'data': np.hstack(data)})
```

Now you should be able to load in Matlab (should be stored to `data` variable)

```
>> load('/path/to/output400_flickr_fc7.mat');
```

Comment: Thank you @Shai, I will try this

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [this](https://github.com/kyamagu/matlab-leveldb) git project?
This project seems to implement a wrapper for reading leveldb datasets into matlab.

Comment: thank you for helping me. Ok, I will check that git project.

Comment: thats project is designed for UNIX. But, now i am working on windows. So do you have any recommendation?

Comment: the data is read from leveldb as string, how would you convert it to image?